# Какой аналог register_next_step_handler для R?

Tags: telegram-bot, r, rstudio

Создаю чат-бот в телеграмме на R, который будет выполнять некие математические операции с функцией, введенной пользователем.

Никак не могу понять как сохранить ответ пользователя в переменную. Пыталась сохранить `message$text` в фильтре сообщений, но Rstudio ругается:

> Error in if (handler$check_update(update)) { : argument is not interpretable as logical

Вот код фильтров и хендлеры:

```r
MessageFilters$func <- BaseFilter(function(message) {
  # проверяем, встречается ли в тексте сообщения нужные слова
  grepl(x           = message$text,
        pattern     = 'x',
        ignore.case = TRUE)
  users_function <- message$text
}
)

MessageFilters$params <- BaseFilter(function(message) {
  grepl(x           = message$text,
        pattern     = ',',
        ignore.case = TRUE)
  
  res <- strsplit(message$text, ",")
  
  a <- as.numeric(res[[1]][1])
  b <- as.numeric(res[[1]][2])
  n <- as.numeric(res[[1]][3])
}
)

menu_txt_h <- MessageHandler(parameters, filters = MessageFilters$func)
parameters_txt_h <- MessageHandler(choise, filters = MessageFilters$params)
```